# SQLite claims duplicate rows on insert whereas none can be found

Tags: ruby, sqlite, duplicates, sequel

I have a table in a SQLite database created with the code below. Note the compound primary key:

```
db.create_table(:person_hash) do
  Integer :person_id
  Bignum :hash // MD5 hash in hex stored as numeric: hash.to_i(16)
  primary_key [:person_id, :hash]
end
```

This table has some rows already:

```
puts db[:person_hash].where(:person_id => 285577).all
# {:person_id=>285577, :hash=>306607097659338192312932577746542919680}
```

Now, when I try to insert this:

```
db[:person_hash].insert({:person_id=>285577, :hash=>306607097659338206333361532286405644297})
```

I get this:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: columns person_id, hash are not unique (Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

**If the row does not already exist in the table, how can it be a duplicate?**

I tried inserting another hash for the same person ID instead, and it worked without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in SQLite:

`$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.9 OpenBSD
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE person_hash (person_id integer, hash bigint, primary key (person_id, hash));
sqlite> INSERT INTO person_hash VALUES (285577, 306607097659338192312932577746542919680);
sqlite> INSERT INTO person_hash VALUES (285577, 306607097659338206333361532286405644297);
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: person_hash.person_id, person_hash.hash`

Comment: Transferred the data to a new table with a surrogate PK instead. Knew I could count on you. Thanks! The interesting this is that such a bug disables the whole feature of composite keys, at least in the situation seen here where the PKs are the only columns in the table.